# What is the purpose of this array after the returned object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Can someone describe the purpose of [this.props.currency] placed after the return object or a place I can read about this pattern, as I haven't seen it before.

I am not asking what this.props.currency is but rather it's purpose after the returned object.

Seen on this blog post:
https://javascriptplayground.com/react-extracting-logic/

```
export const getCurrencyData = currency => {
    return {
        GBP: { base: 100, symbol: '£' },
        USD: { base: 100, symbol: '$' },
      }[this.props.currency];
    };
```

Comment: It's just indexing into the object. Presumably `this.props.currency` will contain either `GBP` or `USD` and return the corresponding element. What's not as clear is why the function takes a `currency` argument.

Comment: Thank you. I think the article mentions the currency parameter is a mistake. I see now that this is just bracket notation. I just don't usually see it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it does is it gets the value of the property with the key of `this.props.currency` - so if `currency` is `"GBP"`, the value returned is `{ base: 100, symbol: "£" }`. You can write it like this to make it clearer:

```
export const getCurrencyData = currency => {
    const obj = {
        GBP: { base: 100, symbol: '£' },
        USD: { base: 100, symbol: '$' }
      };
      return obj[this.props.currency];
};
```

You could also take advantage of the explicit return feature with arrow functions to remove the `return` keyword:

```
export const getCurrencyData = currency => ({
    GBP: { base: 100, symbol: '£' },
    USD: { base: 100, symbol: '$' },
}[this.props.currency]);
```

Comment: Isn't it potentially problematic to have a function that expects [this.props.currency] to be in scope as opposed to simply passing it in explicitly as an argument? Is the only thing gained by writing this way, getting a really concise function? Or is there something more?

Also doing it this way means you the function is not reusable as opposed to the parameter approach where you can pass in differently named variables.

Comment: Not too good with React, however I believe the `this.props` is required. I would personally do it with the passed `currency` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Currency is key of the part of the object you are looking for.

You could rewrite that as:

```
function getCurrencyData(currency) {
  const allAvailableData = {
    GBP: { base: 100, symbol: '£' },
    USD: { base: 100, symbol: '$' },
  }

  return allAvailableData[currency]
}

console.log(getCurrencyData('GBP'))
// { base: 100, symbol: '£' }
console.log(getCurrencyData('USD'))
// { base: 100, symbol: '$' }
```